# React Native google autocomplete search bar in iOS gray cross icon remove

Tags: ios, react-native, google-maps, searchbar, google-places-autocomplete

in my react native app I am using `react-native-google-places-autocomplete` plugin for google search so in iOS by default gray icon come in the search bar for cancel check bar below image
https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete

[image]

My code as below

```js
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
  placeholder={props.placeholder}
  onPress={(data, details = null) => props.onPress(data, details)}
  onFail={(error) => console.error('error-->', error)}
  ref={ref}
  query={{
    key: '*****',
    language: 'en',
    region: 'ae',
    components: 'country:ae',
    types: 'geocode', // default: 'geocode'
  }}
  numberOfLines={1}
  fetchDetails={true}
  renderDescription={(row) => row.description}
  renderRightButton={() => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => ref.current?.setAddressText('')}>
      <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', flex: 1, alignSelf: 'center' }}>
        <FastImage
          source={images.shippingAddress.cross_dark}
          style={{ width: 24, height: 24, marginRight: 10 }}
          resizeMode={'contain'}
        />
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )}
  nearbyPlacesAPI="GooglePlacesSearch" // Which API to use: GoogleReverseGeocoding or GooglePlacesSearch
  styles={{
    textInputContainer: {
      //   backgroundColor: 'red',
      marginLeft: 20,
      marginRight: 20,
      flexDirection: 'row',
      borderRadius: 30,
      borderColor: colors.white,
      borderWidth: 1,
      backgroundColor: colors.white,
    },
    textInput: {
      height: 40,
      color: colors.black,
      fontSize: globals.font_14,
      marginTop: 5,
      backgroundColor: 'white',
    },
    predefinedPlacesDescription: {
      color: colors.red,
    },
    poweredContainer: {
      marginRight: 20,
      marginLeft: 20,
    },
    row: {
      marginHorizontal: 20,
    },
    separator: {
      backgroundColor: '#c1bfc5',
      height: 0.7,
    },
  }}
/>
```

Is there any way how I can remove the gray cancel icon from the google component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable it in `textInputProps` using [`clearButtonMode`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#clearbuttonmode-ios).

```js
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
...
  textInputProps={
    clearButtonMode: false,
  }
...
/>
```

Comment: clearButtonMode: 'never',

Answer (score 1):

```js
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
...
  textInputProps={
    clearButtonMode: 'never',
  }
...
/>
```

Comment: It is the same answer as currently provided on the question. 
But initial answer contains more information (link to doc) of the suggested property.